# Hot to make array of elements from array of tuples in fsharp

Tags: arrays, f#, tuples

The goal is to make from for example from [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)] this array [|1,2,3,4,5,6|]. Msdn gives a simple [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee353905.aspx) of Array.collect's usage. I tried to do the same with

```
x |> Array.collect (fun (a,b) -> [|a,b|])
```

but it still returns (a,b)[].
Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your lambda creates array of one tuple `[|a,b|]`
You need array of two elements: `(fun (a,b) -> [|a; b|])` 
Elements in collections are divided by `;`

Comment: thanks a lot! Such an obvious mastake! I just need to sleep a bit :)